# Retrieve the last month rows from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a problem regarding fetching the data of the last one month.

As my table doesn't have any `DateTime` column, is there is any chance to get the last one month's rows from the table?

Comment: Are there *any* fields at all from which you can infer when the data was written?  A FK to another table?  An identity column (which can be assumed to always be incrementing over time unless you manually interfered with it)? Because, if it's not in the data, it's not possible to do.

Comment: All i can suggest is to check for change traces (as far as I know, you can create a trace database by running the SQL Server Profiler. It should trace any changes made to anything bound to the instance you connected to) but yeah, there is no way to query recent data without a datetame field

Comment: Last hope is that you have a trigger on the table that logs activity against it, and you can infer the record keys from that log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible. You have to have any columns indicating the timestamp.

If you know the number of rows being added in a specific period then you can calculate an approximate output.

Comment: Thanks
:( no i don't have the DateTime column in the table.
and not even the adding date

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible as there is no way to query for the creation date of a record if you haven't defined such a column

Answer (score 0):

You might have chance if any column even if its varchar also is giving you the hint for date then just cast that column into datetime and fetch max of that column.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Tracking Method For This Table
or Use Log File To Get time of Insert or Update Rows